# Let Window scroll down in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

So I am trying to learn Java now that I know JavaScript and PHP. I am working in Netbeans with JavaFX and I am trying to create a program that creates 5 buttons. (This is modifying the code that comes with Netbeans when creating a new JavaFX Application.) If I change the y-argument of the scene to be less than the y of all of the buttons, it will not display the remaining buttons and it will not be able scroll down. This is what I have so far. How do I enable it to scroll down so all buttons can be seen? I know that I can just change the scene back to its old height but I want to learn about scrolling with JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Button[] btn=new Button[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            btn[i] = new Button();
            btn[i].setText(i+"");
            GridPane.setRowIndex(btn[i],i); 
            root.getChildren().addAll(btn[i]);
            btn[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("This is a button");
            }
        });

        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 50);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ScrollPane to set root as:

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setContent(root);

Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 300, 50);
```